# Cut out image sections from a rotated image with a maximum of 10% filled pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, crop

I've been using Python for a while, haven't really had any contact with CV2 yet.

As a starting point, I have a 1280x720 pixel image, which I filled up to 1475x1475 pixels. The image is now rotated by a certain angle, which can be variable.

[image: Original Image] [image: Filled image] [image: rotated image][image: cropped Image]

I would now like to cut out as many sections as possible from this rotated image, with the size 224x224. The proportion of filled pixels should be a maximum of 10% in the cropped image. The cutouts should not be overlapped but should be next to and on top of each other.

Do I have to create a mask with the filled pixels and then define the sections from it, or can I do that with an if query and count the filled pixels?

Since these are some images, I think that the if statement takes a bit long.

I would be happy to get an answer.

Attached is the previous code.

```
img = cv2.imread("maxresdefault.jpg")
background_size = 1475

background = np.ones((background_size, background_size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
start_y = (background_size - img.shape[0]) // 2
start_x = (background_size - img.shape[1]) // 2
background[start_y:start_y+img.shape[0], start_x:start_x+img.shape[1]] = img

angle = 60
rot_point = (background_size//2,background_size//2)
rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rot_point,angle,1.0)
img_rot = cv2.warpAffine(background,rot_mat,(background_size,background_size))
```

I tried this, asking if 10% of the filled pixels are there. However, I still get completely black images in places.

```
# Define the size of the cropped regions
crop_size = 224  # Crop size of 224x224

# Create an empty list to store the valid cropped regions
valid_cropped_images = []

# Loop through the image to extract cropped regions
for y in range(0, img_rot.shape[0] - crop_size + 1, crop_size):
    for x in range(0, img_rot.shape[1] - crop_size + 1, crop_size):
        # Crop the region
        cropped = img_rot[y : y + crop_size, x : x + crop_size]
        
        # Calculate the proportion of filled pixels in the cropped region
        black_pixel_count = np.count_nonzero(np.all(cropped == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1))
        total_pixel_count = cropped.shape[0] * cropped.shape[1]
        black_pixel_ratio = black_pixel_count / total_pixel_count
        # Add the cropped region to the list if the proportion of filled pixels <= 0.1 (10%)
        if black_pixel_ratio <= 0.1:
            valid_cropped_images.append(cropped)
```

[image: Cropped Image]

The original image can be downloaded [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZxD5FTQRmtsxoo5FszaozV2dx-4DHXJy/view)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76907149/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why not unrotate and crop.

Comment: @Woodford sorry you are right I updated the post.

Comment: @fmw42 This is just an example image, in the original image I have lines that I aligned in one direction. The cutouts should then maintain this orientation, with as few filled pixels as possible. If I first generate the crops and then rotate, I get the black pixels again.

Comment: look into saliency. -- [mre] must include data, i.e. the picture, not a plot of a picture. you are forcing everyone to take your plot into a photo editor and crop off the debris that isn't "picture"